# Spring Tiles Framework : refresh only body content when change select option in header

Tags: spring-mvc, tiles

i have three jsp's i.e header.jsp,body.jsp,footer.jsp.i am using tiles in spring mvc.i have one select option box in header.jsp.when i change select option box content in header.jsp then i need to change body content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the solution for this question. i am using jqxgrid.